# Jenkins cannot find sh script in git repo

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my git repo I have build script located in `/Src/build.sh`. I have set up simple Jenkins file which runs this script:

```
node {
    stage 'Checkout'
        checkout scm

    stage 'Build'
        sh "chmod +x ./Src/build.sh"
        sh "./Src/build.sh"
}
```

Execution of `chmod` seems to be successfull, but running `build.sh` gives me this error:

```
+ ./Src/build.sh
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/wrksp@tmp/durable-d3f345e7/script.sh: 1: 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/wrksp@tmp/durable-d3f345e7/script.sh: ./Src/build.sh: not found
```

I have no idea what is wrong?

Comment: Please check the line ending \n vs \r\n on 1st line. it might be windows style endins makes such jokes. Do you have a shebang in the beginning of the script? if so. please check whether the mentioed sh exist on sistem

Comment: @KSI that was it, thank you!